# springBootVersion = '2.0.0.M6' fails immediately after start using java9

Tags: java, spring-boot

Trying to start basic application with spring boot version 2.0.0.M6 with java 9, gradle 4.3 but its shuttinh down immediately after start,

build.gradle file looks like this,

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.0.M6'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'war'

group = 'test.com'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility =9.0

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services')
    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')
    providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Console looks like this,

```
2017-11-08 16:31:01.268  INFO 7704 --- [  restartedMain] dk.danskespil.ebu.EbuApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default

2017-11-08 16:31:01.369  INFO 7704 --- [  restartedMain] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@52c4a7bc: startup date [Wed Nov 08 16:31:01 CET 2017]; root of context hierarchy

WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred

WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1 (file:/C:/Users/amga/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-core/5.0.1.RELEASE/1e0344e553a5ff714f299096216769beffd0d291/spring-core-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)

WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1

WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations

WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

2017-11-08 16:31:02.876  INFO 7704 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729

2017-11-08 16:31:02.913  INFO 7704 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup

2017-11-08 16:31:02.932  INFO 7704 --- [  restartedMain] dk.danskespil.ebu.EbuApplication         : Started EbuApplication in 2.556 seconds (JVM running for 4.056)

2017-11-08 16:31:02.936  INFO 7704 --- [       Thread-7] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@52c4a7bc: startup date [Wed Nov 08 16:31:01 CET 2017]; root of context hierarchy

2017-11-08 16:31:02.939  INFO 7704 --- [       Thread-7] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
```

Answer (score 0):

removal of org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat solved the problem.

org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web contains spring-boot-starter-tomcat so there is no need of adding it separately.

Spring boot 2.0.0.M6 with gradle 4.3  and java 9 works fine now.

Comment: How did the removal solve the problem? Would be good to add to the answer to actually make it useful.

Comment: I tried staring the application only with spring-boot-starter-web and it ran without any problem. Then read the purpose of having spring-boot-starter-tomcat and starter-web dependencies at,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33419823/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-vs-spring-boot-starter-web

Comment: in build.gradle commented the below code,                  //providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')

Comment: Actually I'm not convinced why it was a problem with having both of them together, but removal of it and  assuring that I have a container in starter-web resolved the problem.