# Maven dependency pickup in springboot

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I have declared these two dependencies

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>   
     <scope>provided</scope> 
</dependency>
```

and :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

`spring-boot-starter-web`  already has `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` with embedded tomcat-core. As shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/33419889/1171533

My question is  when my project is build and run which of the implementations of `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` is chosen to run? And how can I find which one is being used?

Answer (score 2):

Run `mvn dependency:tree`.

Look for this line:

```
...
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:<version>:provided
...
```

If you delete

```xml
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>   
     <scope>provided</scope> 
</dependency>
```

the previous output line should be gone and this gets added instead:

```
...
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:<version>:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:<version>:compile
...
```

Comment: This is the good answer. You can also open the different tab of pom.xml in eclipse to explore this, you will see precisely which version takes precedence on which when u have conflicting declaration. In you example, you are declaring the same version twice (implicit version from spring boot parent), so there is no conflict.

Answer (score 1):

Based on a class instance, you can find various information of the jar that contains that class.

```
yourInstance.getClass().getPackage().getImplementationVersion()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using @RestController(means creating restful services) below dependency you can use

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

if you are using theamleaf , jsp (you want to deploy application as war) you need to include following dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```