# Tomcat and spring-boot-starter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I have some Spring Boot 2.1 applications and they are all hosted on Tomcat 8.5
We normally use the following POM.xml structure:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The issue we are facing is about the size, we realized that spring-boot-started takes a lot of MB, while we have another application which is using only: `spring-boot-starter-web` and `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` and the size jump down from 50MB to 10MB.

Assuming we only use Tomcat, **except for development** where we use `mvn spring-boot run`, what happens if I remove `spring-boot-starter`? Can I have an application with only `spring-boot-starter-web` and `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` but still being able to use `mvn spring-boot run` during development?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33419823/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-vs-spring-boot-starter-web#33419889) answer by *ltalhouarne*.

> `spring-boot-starter-web` contains spring web dependencies (including `spring-boot-starter-tomcat`):
>
> `spring-boot-starter`
> `jackson`
> `spring-core`
> `spring-mvc`
> `spring-boot-starter-tomcat`

Simply including `spring-boot-starter-web` should be enough.

Comment: Super, I'll do that. It should drastically reduce the .war size