j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
I have this big problem here when I try to run the ApiRestFul that I created in Spring Boot. The interesting thing is that it does not throw an error when launching the application. But this unexpected closure of the JPA EntityManagerFactory occurs and of course this prevents me from testing it with Postman because since the application is not working it gives a connection error. The error is strong because I have already consulted several solutions on this channel, I have tried them and nothing... can anyone of you help please?
Here the application.Properties
#configuracion de la base de datos
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/SpringBootRest
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=123456

#Configuración de Hibernate
spring.jpa.database-platform= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialectyour text
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
and here the problem or the warning that it shows when executing
2024-10-16T09:26:45.360-04:00  INFO 8736 --- [           main] c.a.rest.SpringBootRestApplicationTests  : Started SpringBootRestApplicationTests in 3.351 seconds (process running for 4.108)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended
2024-10-16T09:26:45.754-04:00  INFO 8736 --- [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-10-16T09:26:45.756-04:00  INFO 8736 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...`your text`
2024-10-16T09:26:45.761-04:00  INFO 8736 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

Process finished with exit code 0

I tried to get the application to run but it always ended with the unexpected closing.
Any idea what is happening and its possible solution?

first answer in google usually helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69619425/closing-jpa-entity-manage-factory-for-persistence-unit-default

This help gives an idea of ​​the possible error but does not solve the problem, I have already tried these solutions and nothing. Is there any other possibility to solve this problem? I don't have spring-boot-starter-tomcat in my pom.xml but this issue still worries me.
I updated the parent version "spring-boot-starter-parent to 3.3.4 and nothing, the problem persists

do you have running MySql docker? "docker run --name mysql -p 3306:3306 -h localhost -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456 -d mysql/mysql-server:latest"

I have a xampp server and it works, I am not using Docker and I am testing locally.  Here is the project on github =>https://github.com/djaimes99/ApiRestFul-with-SpringBoot

The problem is solved. So we do that:
To ensure your file uses the correct encoding, especially UTF-8, follow these steps:

Save the file (application.properties) with UTF-8 encoding
Use a text editor that allows you to specify encoding when saving files. Editors like Notepad++, Visual Studio Code, or IntelliJ IDEA allow you to check and change the coding.
In Notepad++, you can change the encoding by going to and then saving the file.Encoding > Convert to UTF-8. After saving the file, we run the application again with Maven => Spring Boot: run and that's it!!


Don't forget that it is recommended to use version 17 of JDK (I was using version 22 ), then do what it says in this video: =>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O5bnhSwd_ac&t=2s and run the application with Maven (as this video indicates), not with Coverage as I was doing.
this!!
