# "Unable to start embedded container" after switch from tomcat to jetty,Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jetty, embedded-jetty

I have a demo spring boot application following the guide https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

But I hope to use jetty container rather than tomcat , so I use the following pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0        http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>cn.webank</groupId>
    <artifactId>wemq-manager</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>


        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>-->
            <!--<scope>test</scope>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
        </dependency>




    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>




@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("cn.webank.wemqhttp")
public class ServerStartup {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServerStartup.class, args);
    }
}
```

This throws an exception after I add fragments that switch to jetty and run `ServerStartup`(This runs fine before I try to switch to jetty)

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:535) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at cn.webank.wemqhttp.boot.ServerStartup.main(ServerStartup.java:22) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134) [idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:189) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
```

PS: Since the startup class is not at the same package of my beans, so I have explicitly add @ComponentScan to my startup class.

Comment: Dependencies and Bootstrap-Class look fine to me. Can you please provide the full pom.xml? btw. you can leave out the `ComponentScan`. It's part of `SpringBootApplication`

Comment: @DanielBubenheim - a side note - you say he can remove ComponentScan, however it depends how his Configuration is setup (the default ComponentScan picks up everything from the current package), perhaps he wants some Configuration to be ignored ? Anyway, even so, I agree that the best practice would still be to remove it and fix/remove any unwanted Configuration

Comment: @Alex Of course you're right about `ComponentScan`and packaging. But I wanted to keep the example simple to avoid any other problems. Thanks for pointing that out explicitly!

Comment: @DanielBubenheim check the updated question for entire pom.xml

Comment: you are building and launching from intellij ?

Comment: @Alex , yes, but I also tried ecplise , the same problem

Comment: try deleting your ~/.m2/repository and rebuilding

Comment: @Alex, the same problem

Comment: @Jaskey There is nothing wrong with the pom file as far as I can see. The only thing I would ask is what you need the repositories definitions for? If you want to you can try out an easy example that I've set up. Let me know if this works for you or not: https://github.com/dbubenheim/spring-boot-demo

Comment: @DanielBubenheim , I clone your repo and the same problem, but I use java.version=1.7 rather than 1.8 since I have only java 7 installed

Comment: @Jaskey Then I think the problem is somehow related to your local environment. Did you check port 8080 to be open? And by the way did you try out to remove the `ComponentScan` to search for beans in all packages?

Comment: @DanielBubenheim , I use your githup repo ,which should not have ComponentScan and I have this work successfully by using tomcat, this is only not work well using jetty's pom.

Comment: that sounds really strange. did you already try it on a different machine? it has to be something specifically related to the embedded jetty libs

Comment: @DanielBubenheim I tries three maches(two of mine, and one of my collegue) , the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-all-server</artifactId>
    <version>8.2.0.v20160908</version>
</dependency>
```

You may also comment the `dependency` with the `artifactId` of `spring-boot-starter-jetty`.